# Running the following on python

Tags: python

trying to get a program to enter a students name and score, test it to make sure score is a vaule >=0 and <=100 and save results to a file and loop back

```
 gradeFile = open("grade.dat","a")
    Score = "0"
    while Score>=0:
        Name = raw_input("What is the students's name?: ")
        Score = float(raw_input("What is the students's score?: "))
         while Score <0 or Score >100 :
            print("ERROR: the grade cannot be less than 0 or more than 100")
            Score = float(raw_input("What is the students's score?: "))
        gradeFile.write(Name+"\n")
        gradeFile.write(Score+"\n")
    gradeFile.close()
    print("Data saved to grade.dat")
```

Comment: gradeFile.write(Score+"\n") gives you error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'`, you can change it to gradeFile.write(str(Score)+"\n")

Comment: You didn't ask a question. What question about your task do you need answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a way to exit the loop.  For your outer loop, you automatically go in.  Then you loop again until you get a valid score, via your inner loop, and you repeat.  In your current configuration, there's no way to exit the loop.

Additionally, score should be a number, but you enter it as a string in `Score = "0"`.  When outputting, you're going to want to write `str(Score)` so that you can concatenate it with `"\n"`.

I suggest that your outer loop have something like `while Score >= 0 and userWantsToContinue`.  You can handle `userWantsToContinue` in whatever way you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

Your datatpe doesn't match

```
Score = "0"  # So, score is a string
while Score >= 0:  # Oh, thenm it's a integer?
```